# image does not download with it's own extension

Tags: javascript, download

I have used below code to download image with given name. But this seems does not download image with it's own image extension.

Here is HTML

```
<a id="btnDownload" href="www.mywebsite.com/images/myimage.jpg" onClick="downloadImage(www.mywebsite.com/images/myimage.jpg);" >download</a>
```

and code

```
function downloadImage(sUrl){    
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', sUrl, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        var res = xhr.response;
        var blob = new Blob([res], {type:'image'});
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "My image name";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

What i want is i want downloaded image with "My image name"."extension". Here image does have alternative extension like jpeg, png, gif.
But this code always download file without extension. Any changes here?

Comment: You could just add `download` attribute in your `a` tag.

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps the `{type:'image'}` part should refer to a complete mime type identifier, like `image/jpeg` for exampla.

Comment: First of all the parameter should be a string or more simple this.href.

Comment: Maybe you can try this `<a id="btnDownload" href="www.mywebsite.com/images/myimage.jpg" download>`

Comment: @Thum Choon Tat: Has no IE support.. neither has the OP solution tho.

Comment: Simply adding download it download image but not with custom name.

Comment: Just parse your url to extract the extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the extension in your example you could do:

```
a.download = "My image Name." + window.URL.split('.').pop();
```

Yet I would work with different data-attributes:

```
<html>
    <!--
        You can put the href and the name you want to see in different data attributes.
        Also one can add IE support.
    -->

    <head>
        <script>
            //e:=<a [data-name] [data-href]>
            function downloadMe(e){
                var tF = e.getAttribute('data-name');
                var tURL = e.getAttribute('data-href')

                var tR = new XMLHttpRequest();
                tR.open('GET', tURL, true);
                tR.responseType = 'blob';

                tR.onload = function(e){
                    var tB = this.response;

                    if(window.top.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
                        //Store Blob in IE
                        window.top.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(tB, tF)
                    }
                    else{
                        //Store Blob in others
                        var tA = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
                        tA.href = URL.createObjectURL(tB);
                        tA.download = tF;
                        tA.style.display = 'none';
                        tA.click();
                        tA.parentNode.removeChild(tA)
                    }
                };

                tR.send();

                return false
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href = '#' data-href = 'A.png' data-name = 'My Name.png' onclick = 'return downloadMe(this)'>download</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added a fix for your way :)